# Telerik (kendo-ui) scheduler with Asp.net MVC not showing appointments in Day and Week view for grayed cells

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik, scheduler

I have used the telerik aspnet mvc schedular for showing and appointment. I am facing an isuue with that in month view all appointment showing, but in day view and week view some appointment goes to missing somehow. I am very new for the scheduler.

View Code

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<AppointmentModel>()
                                .Name("scheduler")
                                .StartTime(0, 0, 0)
                                .WorkDayStart(0, 0, 0)
                                .Height(600)
                                .AllDaySlot(false)
                                .Selectable(false)
                                .Editable(true)
                                 .DataSource(d => d
                                     .Model(m =>
                                     {
                                         m.Id(f => f.AppointmentId);
                                         m.Field(f => f.Title).DefaultValue("No title");
                                     })
                                    .Read("Read", "Appointment"))
                                .EventTemplate(
                                    "<div class='movie-template'>" +
                                    "<a aid='#= id #' href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='LoadToolTip(this);' class='tooltip_display'>#= kendo.toString(start, 'hh:mm') # - #= kendo.toString(end, 'hh:mm') # : #= title # </a>" +
                                    "</div>")
                                .Views(views =>
                                           {
                                               views.DayView();
                                               views.WeekView();
                                               views.MonthView();

                                           })
                                .Resources(resource => resource.Add(m => m.DoctorId)
                                                           .Title("Owner")
                                                           .DataTextField("FirstName")
                                                           .DataValueField("UserId")
                                                           .DataColorField("DoctorColor")
                                                           .BindTo(doctors))

                                .Events(e =>
                                            {
                                                e.Add("scheduler_add");
                                                e.Edit("scheduler_edit");
                                            })
                                )
```

Controller code

```
  public virtual JsonResult Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        return Json(_appointmentService.GetQueryable(CurrentSession.CurrentUser.OrganizationId).ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need "JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet" in your return.

Try this please ..

public ActionResult Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)

{

var e = _appointmentService.GetQueryable(CurrentSession.CurrentUser.OrganizationId);

return Json(e.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}